# Trying to get my discord bot to take a message as number input

Tags: input, discord, discord.py, bots

```
   await message.channel.send("please input the radius of the circle")
   alg(int(message.content()))
   await message.channel.send(alg)
```

every time I input a number after the first message I get the below error.

````
File "main.py", line 138, in on_message
    alg(int(message.content()))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable```
````

Answer (score 3):

`Message.content` is an attribute, not a method - means it shouldn't be called (remove the parenthesis)

```py
int(message.content)
```